# Как отправить запрос через российский сервер?

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Если отправить следующий запрос с локального компьютера (Россия), то `trackCount` будет больше нуля. Если запрос будет с зарубежного сервера, например, [replit](https://replit.com), ответ придет, но без треков.

```py
url = 'https://api.music.yandex.net/users/music-blog/playlists/1103'
response = get(url)
print(response.json()['result']['trackCount'])
```

Можно пропустить запрос через российский сервер, если изначально он идет из того же replit? Попробовал бесплатные прокси, не помогло, тоже ноль треков.

Comment: а точно ли ответ вам приходит?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, ответ приходит. Со всеми данными о плейлисте (название, описание, обложка и тд), а массив с треками пустой. Это можно также увидеть, если с локального компьютера через впн в браузере сходить по этой ссылке.